# Fourier Transformation in R

Tags: r

is there a simple solution to get a fourier transformation of a specific signal? I've tried it with GeneCycle but the outcome seems to be wrong.

The signal: https://www.sendspace.com/file/bmwjvr

My code that I tried:

```
trajectory <- testmatrix[,2]
library(GeneCycle)
f.data <- GeneCycle::periodogram(trajectory)
harmonics <- 2:10
plot(f.data$freq[harmonics]*length(trajectory), 
f.data$spec[harmonics]/sum(f.data$spec), 
xlab="Harmonics", ylab="Amplitute Density", type="h")
```

Comment: [This tutorial](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/fourier/fourier.html) might be of relevance. Also, try running `example(periodogram)` and take a look at the code.

Comment: I've tried that tutorial, however RStudio told me that there is no function called "plot.frequency.spectrum" and I wasn't able to find it on the internet qhat package it requires.

Comment: He define that function in the tutorial, try searching for "plot a frequency spectrum of a given" on [the tutorial page](http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/fourier/fourier.html).

Comment: `plot.frequency.spectrum` is a function that is defined in the tutorial. It is not part of a package. You just need to copy and run the function code from the tutorial to make the function available in your R session.